# HTML Sanitizer for .NET that supports style tags

Tags: c#, .net, css, vb.net, security

I'm looking for a good HTML sanitizer to use in an ASP.NET project. The catch is that the sanitizer must support style attributes, which may contain CSS properties, which must also be sanitized. So far I haven't been able to find a good product to use. Before I bite the bullet and write my own sanitizer, I thought I might try to see what people here are using first.

Libraries that I've looked at and rejected:

- AntiXSS Library (old version is insecure, new version strips style tags)
- AntiSamy .NET (unmaintained, lacks necessary features in the .NET version, has obsolete dependencies)
- The HTMLAgilityPackSanitizer in AjaxControlToolkit (escapes style tags)

The ideal would be to have a whitelist-based sanitizer that also validates property values against a list of known values or regexes.

Anybody able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) is old but i've used it with success.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's what I'm looking for, though. The primary goal here here is to ensure that user input does not contain executable scripts. HTML Tidy looks nice, but seems to have a very different purpose.

Answer (score 5):

Try [this native .NET HTML Sanitizer project](https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer). It can understand style attributes as you want (though it doesn't try and preserve STYLE tags, it just removes them).

Additionally it's whitelist based, rather than blacklist (and it uses AngleSharp instead of CsQuery which is now deprecated). It's also [on Nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlSanitizer/)!

Answer (score 3):

Look at [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/csquery) (which I am the primary author of) as a tool for manipulating HTML.

This is a .NET jQuery port, it provides you with complete access to HTML via the same methods you would use on the client (a DOM and jQuery's API). This makes it pretty easy to roll your own sanitizer.

Rick Strahl had a [blog post](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Jul/19/NET-HTML-Sanitation-for-rich-HTML-Input) recently about sanitizing HTML. He showed how to do it with his rules using HTML Agility Pack, I posted a comment there showing how to achieve the same thing more easily with CsQuery. The basics are just this, given an enumeration of tags `BlackList`:

```
CQ doc = CQ.Create(html);

// creates a grouped selector "iframe,form,script, ..."
string selector = String.Join(",",BlackList); 

// CsQuery uses the property indexer as a default method, it's identical 
// to the "Select" method and functions like $(...)

doc[selector].Remove();
```

If you don't want to actually remove content in some tags, e.g. perhaps formatting tags you wish to prohibit, you can use jQuery's unwrap instead. This would have the effect of removing a tag but preserving its children.

```
doc[selector].UnWrap();
```

When you're done:

```
string cleanHtml = doc.Render();
```

There's more at Ricks' post for cleaning up javascript event attributes and so on, but basically CsQuery is a toolbox with a familiar and simple way to manipulate HTML. It should be easy enough to create a sanitizer that works in the way you want.

CsQuery's DOM model also contains methods to access the styles directly (e.g. in a more convenient way than just manipulating the string), if you need to do something like remove certain named styles. For example you could remove the "font-weight" style from all elements:

```
// use the [attribute] selector to target only elements with styles

foreach (IDomObject element in doc["[style]"]) {
    if (element.HasStyle("font-weight")) {
        element.RemoveStyle("font-weight");
    }
}
```

The major shortcoming of CsQuery right now is documentation. It's API is designed to match the browser DOM and jQuery as closely as possible (given language differnces between jQuery and C#), and the public API is well commented, so it should be easy enough to code against once you get going.

But there are a handful of nonstandard methods (like "HasStyle" and "RemoveStyle" that) are unique to CsQuery. Basic usage is covered pretty well in the readme on github, though. It's also on Nuget as `CsQuery`.

Comment: Cool. If I do end up rolling my own sanitizer, that seems like a good tool to look into.

Comment: I'm going to give this a go and make my own whitelist sanitizer. I'm assuming I can just use an "all" selector and then iterate and unwrap any not in my whitelist (or potentially use a not-predicate selector if they exist?)

Comment: I can't think of a reason that wouldn't work. I don't have a good sense for whether that would be more or less efficient than using tag selector to just target the tags you want in the first place (same technique as the blacklist example I give), would probably depend on the good to bad ratio, but for this purpose it's probably such a small amount of content it wouldn't really matter either way.

Comment: Does Unwrap do what is intended here? It seems that unwrapping removes the parent, not the tag itself

Comment: OK, I think the sample code above should read:  `doc[selector].Contents.UnWrap();`

Answer (score 0):

Tatham Oddie ASP.Net MVP - http://blog.tatham.oddie.com.au/2009/06/15/released-xhtml-markup-sanitizer/

I've referred this to a few people now. May not do everything you want but Tatham's an awesome coder so it should give you plenty of ideas...

Just on the AntiXSS, AFAIK the new version is in HTMLAgilityPackSanitizer

Comment: Thanks, but neither of those is suitable for my purposes, as they both encode special characters within attributes. This is good for security because there are plenty of XSS hacks you can do in a style attribute, but I need to be able to allow the good stuff. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the HtmlSanitizer posted on the open lab blog: http://roberto.open-lab.com/2010/03/04/a-html-sanitizer-for-c/ . This one supports style tags and is pretty good to use for html editors.

Comment: Thanks. That's the closest I've seen, but I'm not a fan of the blacklist approach. For example, it doesn't consider "behavior" to be a forbidden string in style attributes even though you can execute scripts in IE through behaviors. There are probably other things you can do that I, and the author, don't know about. I'm also concerned that it doesn't parse HTML correctly. It may still work, but if you can fool the parser (say, put a ">" character in an attribute value, it will consider the tag to be closed) then you can fool the sanitizer.

Comment: Since I couldn't edit my comment I rewrote it: Well in that case I don't think there is any other way apart from choosing a library as a base and customize it to your needs. It may be a bit of work but that is the only way you really get what you want. We did the same at work (sadly i can't share that code).

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've ended up doing. I was just hoping there might be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Check out **Dead Simple HTML Sanitizer** on CodeProject http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/529712/Dead-Simple-HTML-Sanitizer